# Possible to center and set element width by using percent

Tags: css

I'm trying to center an element with percent, but it don't work! Have I missed something or is the way I'm doing it impossible?

When I'm using this setting, the element is almost touching the top of the browser area.

```
.modal-box {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    margin-left: -25%;  
}
```

Comment: `margin-left: -25;` should probably be `margin-left: -25%;`

Comment: *"center an element with percent,"* -- percent of what? The parent? Or the viewport?

Comment: @Magicprog.fr I just missed the % sign when I wrote the question. This is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @3D-kreativ I know, that's why I put that as a comment and post an answer with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because everything is in %, you should just define `width + height` and `top + left` positions, not margin:

```
.modal-box {
    height: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/ob29nn2u/

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now it's better!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of margins, use a `transform`. This will center the box regardless of height/width.

```css
.modal-box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center with percents, you will need to know the width of an element.

so say `modal-box` was 300px wide, you would do something like this:

```
.modal-box{
width:300px;
position:fixed;
left:50%;
margin-left: -150px; /*1/2 of your divs width*/
}
```

Comment: If you look at my CSS the width of the element is 50%

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding

```
margin-top: -25%;
margin-left: -25;
```

That negates the `position: fixed` of what you were trying to achieve. Remove those two lines and you will see how you can have your fixed position of the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it relative to the viewport (irrespective of parent), then make use of the [viewport-relative-lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

```css
.modal-box {
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 50vw; height: 50vh;
    top: 50vh; left: 50vw;
    margin-top: -25vh; margin-left: -25vw;  
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isn't there some problem with viewport units on some mobile phones like iPhone?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Yes. And there are fixes available for that as well. Anyway, go with your use-case requirement.